# How to configure proxy for JMeter and Chrome and IIS Express

Tags: c#, iis, jmeter, automated-tests, iis-express

I run my solution on IIS Express with address http://localhost:58187/

I try to record some test using JMeter, so I configure Test Script Recorder as you can see below. Port for proxy is 8888.

[image]

After that I set proxy settings in Chrome as you see below.

[image]

After all configuration I click "Start" button in 
But when I go by browser into localhost address I get error **ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**. What made I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your second screenshot contains the answer:

[image: IE Proxy settings]

Try unticking the highlighted box and that should be it.

All other configuration seems to be fine (assuming you don't forget to start JMeter's proxy)

Going forward I would recommend one of the following approaches:

1. Use a browser which has its own proxy settings and don't inherit operating system proxy settings, i.e. [Mozilla Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/desktop/)
2. Use [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension) for recording. In this case you won't have to worry about proxies and SSL certificates, just clicking a button in Chrome browser toolbar will trigger recording.